# What does the ? operator do in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have a function here that checks to see if the last element of an input array is a hash table. If so, it'll remove the last element in the Hash Table.  This is from the solution in Ruby Monk section 6.2.

```
def remove_last(*arguments)
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
end
```

Whats does the '?' operator do between ...(Hash) ? arguments.pop ...

Why is there a ' : {} ' after arguments.pop as well.

Comment: Read an introductory Ruby book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a ternary conditional operator. It has the following form:

```
condition ? true_value : false_value
```

It evaluates the condition, and assumes the value of `true_value` when the condition is true, and the `false_value` when the condition is false.

Comment: Good answer. Concise.

Comment: You should vote to close these questions as off topic due to a lack of basic understanding of the question being asked.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation)

It's like a shortcut to

```
if arguments[-1]is.A?(Hash)
  arguments.pop
else
  {}
end
```

You can use this whenever you have short, concise if statements

Answer (score 0):

It's called the ternary operator

```
(condition) ? (use_this_if_true) : (use_this_if_false)
```

In the example you give, options will contain arguments.pop if arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) otherwise options will contain an empty hash represented by {}